# Can we repair a dead body?

Tags: biochemistry

The following passage has been extracted from the book "Organic Chemistry-10th edition by Solomon and Frhyle":

> "The growth of living things from microbes to elephants rests on organic reactions, and organic reactions provide the energy that drives our muscles and *our thought processes*"

Is the above statement true that, organic reactions provide energy that drives our thought processes? Is there any other process by which we are given energy to drive our thought processes?

If you all agree with the statement, then when a person is called "dead" (or after a while being called dead), I hope the reactions will cease (because he can't perform "thought processes"), isn't it?

If these all points are agreed, is their a possibility of repairing a dead body by restarting the reactions immediately?

I agree that, it is not as easy as I said, there is a complexity, but I believe we all can do some research "together" and try to do a "little" contribution to save ourselves.

So, can we repair a dead body?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find Biochemistry Stack exchange, so I posted here. If this is not the right place, please inform me about where I should post this question.

Comment: There's [Biology.SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com/) where that might be on topic, especially concerning the definition of "death". Also, restarting (high-level) cognitive processes might not induce (low-level) cellular repairs.

Comment: @tschoppi: Is this not on topic here?

Comment: As long as your question only concerns the chemical reactions that provide this energy and alternative sources, this is on topic. But life and death really is more in the realm of biology and ultimately philosophy, so I'd try to cut out as much as possible from that here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's rather a biology question.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. There is no way to reset the transient pulses in the neurons that carry the essence of thought processes. The information is already gone.

You will find the neural synapses all in the discharged state. All thought process, all memory, all of what makes a person is gone.

Comment: This answer is very short and has no explanation. Perhaps you could add some more detail about why this is the case and also comment on the main point of the question which is about the reactions that drive our though processes.

Comment: Could you be a little more elaborate, please? Like I dunno, by saying how you decide that the info is gone, by bringing references or simply by explaining more.